# 2 axes scaling problem

Tags: pgfplots

I have two problems :

the arrow on x axis.

The left y axis does't match all the hight as the right does.
I want on the left axe ymin=0 ymax=25 and the ticks lines in front of the tick lines of the right's one.

I tried with ymin, ymax, and max space between ticks, but nothing good.
[image]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}

% let both axes use the same layers
\pgfplotsset{set layers}

\begin{axis}[%
    scale only axis=true,
    ybar, bar width=10pt, 
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    %axis x line=box,
    axis y line=right,
    symbolic x coords=%
        {Janvier,Février,Mars,Avril,Mai,Juin,Juillet,
        Août,Septembre,Octobre,Novembre,Décembre},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=60,anchor=east},
    legend style={at={(0.1,0.85)}, anchor=south west,legend columns=-1},
    %nodes near coords,
    %nodes near coords align={vertical},
]


\addplot[style={draw=yellow!80!black,fill=yellow!40!white}] coordinates {%
    (Janvier,85)
    (Février,75)
    (Mars,60)
    (Avril,59)
    (Mai,62)
    (Juin,42)
    (Juillet,48)
    (Août,41)
    (Septembre,69)
    (Octobre,80)
    (Novembre,81)
    (Décembre,91)
    } ;

\legend{Précipitations} ;
\end{axis}


%\end{tikzpicture}

%\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis = true,
    ymin=0,
    max space between ticks=28,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    axis x line=none,
    symbolic x coords=%
        {Janvier,Février,Mars,Avril,Mai,Juin,Juillet,
        Août,Septembre,Octobre,Novembre,Décembre},
    legend style={at={(0.1,.93)}, anchor=south west,legend columns=-1},
    ]

\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {%
    (Janvier,9)
    (Février,10)
    (Mars,13)
    (Avril,15)
    (Mai,18)
    (Juin,22)
    (Juillet,24.5)
    (Août,25)
    (Septembre,22.5)
    (Octobre,18)
    (Novembre,13)
    (Décembre,10.5) 
    } ;

\addplot[blue,mark=*] coordinates {%
    (Janvier,3)
    (Février,3.5)
    (Mars,4.5)
    (Avril,6.5)
    (Mai,9.5)
    (Juin,12)
    (Juillet,14)
    (Août,14)
    (Septembre,12)
    (Octobre,9)
    (Novembre,6)
    (Décembre,4)    
    } ;

\legend{Max,Min} ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with the order of your options in the firts subplot.  The `axis y line=right` needs to come before the `enlargelimits` option, otherwise that option is ignored for that axis:

[image: Sample output]

Input encoding issues are different depending on your engine, hence to the two different sets of code below.

## Lualatex or Xelatex

Easiest, as we can just use `utf8` everywhere.

```
% lualatex or xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

% let both axes use the same layers
\pgfplotsset{set layers}

\begin{axis}[%
    scale only axis=true,
    ybar, bar width=10pt, 
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    axis y line=right,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    symbolic x coords={Janvier,Février,Mars,Avril,Mai,Juin,Juillet,
     Août,Septembre,Octobre,Novembre,Décembre},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={rotate=60,anchor=east},
    legend style={at={(0.1,0.85)}, anchor=south west,legend columns=-1},
]

\addplot[style={draw=yellow!80!black,fill=yellow!40!white}] coordinates {%
    (Janvier,85)
    (Février,75)
    (Mars,60)
    (Avril,59)
    (Mai,62)
    (Juin,42)
    (Juillet,48)
    (Août,41)
    (Septembre,69)
    (Octobre,80)
    (Novembre,81)
    (Décembre,91)
    } ;

\legend{Précipitations} ;
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis = true,
    ymin=0,
    max space between ticks=28,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    axis x line=none,
    symbolic x coords={Janvier,Février,Mars,Avril,Mai,Juin,Juillet,Août,Septembre,Octobre,Novembre,Décembre},
    legend style={at={(0.1,.93)}, anchor=south west,legend columns=-1},
    ]

\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {%
    (Janvier,9)
    (Février,10)
    (Mars,13)
    (Avril,15)
    (Mai,18)
    (Juin,22)
    (Juillet,24.5)
    (Août,25)
    (Septembre,22.5)
    (Octobre,18)
    (Novembre,13)
    (Décembre,10.5) 
    } ;

\addplot[blue,mark=*] coordinates {%
    (Janvier,3)
    (Février,3.5)
    (Mars,4.5)
    (Avril,6.5)
    (Mai,9.5)
    (Juin,12)
    (Juillet,14)
    (Août,14)
    (Septembre,12)
    (Octobre,9)
    (Novembre,6)
    (Décembre,4)    
    } ;

\legend{Max,Min} ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Pdflatex

Problem with using accents in symbolic names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

% let both axes use the same layers
\pgfplotsset{set layers}

\begin{axis}[%
    scale only axis=true,
    ybar, bar width=10pt, 
    ymin=0,ymax=100,
    axis y line=right,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    symbolic x coords={Jan,Fev,Mar,Avr,Mai,Jun,Jui,Aou,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels={Janvier,F\'evrier,Mars,Avril,Mai,Juin,Juillet,
    Ao\^ut,Septembre,Octobre,Novembre,D\'ecembre},
    x tick label style={rotate=60,anchor=east},
    legend style={at={(0.1,0.85)}, anchor=south west,legend columns=-1},
]

\addplot[style={draw=yellow!80!black,fill=yellow!40!white}] coordinates {%
    (Jan,85)
    (Fev,75)
    (Mar,60)
    (Avr,59)
    (Mai,62)
    (Jun,42)
    (Jui,48)
    (Aou,41)
    (Sep,69)
    (Oct,80)
    (Nov,81)
    (Dec,91)
    } ;

\legend{Pr\'ecipitations} ;
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
    scale only axis = true,
    ymin=0,
    max space between ticks=28,
    axis y line=left,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    axis x line=none,
    symbolic x coords={Jan,Fev,Mar,Avr,Mai,Jun,Jui,Aou,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec},
    legend style={at={(0.1,.93)}, anchor=south west,legend columns=-1},
    ]

\addplot[red,mark=*] coordinates {%
    (Jan,9)
    (Fev,10)
    (Mar,13)
    (Avr,15)
    (Mai,18)
    (Jun,22)
    (Jui,24.5)
    (Aou,25)
    (Sep,22.5)
    (Oct,18)
    (Nov,13)
    (Dec,10.5) 
    } ;

\addplot[blue,mark=*] coordinates {%
    (Jan,3)
    (Fev,3.5)
    (Mar,4.5)
    (Avr,6.5)
    (Mai,9.5)
    (Jun,12)
    (Jui,14)
    (Aou,14)
    (Sep,12)
    (Oct,9)
    (Nov,6)
    (Dec,4)    
    } ;

\legend{Max,Min} ;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note if you don't use symbolic names at all but just set the tick labels, then you can use `utf8` in these ticklabels and the lengend.  There seems to be some bug that stops this worknig when symbolic names are also present, and one has to result ordinary TeX accents.

Comment: Works just fine. I prefer:
   x axis line style=-,
   axis x line*=bottom,
than box but it is a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: I just left those options as in your original code.

Comment: I agree, but when one change the place of enlarge ... its changes the apparence of bottom and top of the box. When I posted the question didn't know how suppress the arrow. Thank's a lot.

Comment: OK I have updated my answer.